# CSS on hover out text disappears instead of sliding out like image

Tags: css

Can someone explain why does the image slide back nicely and the text disappears right away when you hover out?

```css
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px; 
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#image {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    transition: 1s;
}

.wrapper:hover #image {
    transition: 1s;
    left: -100px;
}

.wrapper:hover .text {
    transition: 1s;
    left: 50%;
}

.text {
  white-space: nowrap; 
  //color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 50%;
  left: 150%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <img id="image" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-q-c-100-100-4.jpg" />
    <div class="text">text</div>
</div>
```

So what I want is that the text also slides out nicely on hover out and not just disappear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to add the `transition` property to the `.text`:

```css
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px; 
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#image {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    transition: 1s;
}

.wrapper:hover #image {
    transition: 1s;
    left: -100px;
}

.wrapper:hover .text {
    transition: 1s;
    left: 50%;
}

.text {
  white-space: nowrap; 
  //color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 50%;
  left: 150%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img id="image" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-q-c-100-100-4.jpg" alt="">
  <div class="text">text</div>
</div>
```